# SOLR 5: Error loading class 'solr.XsltUpdateRequestHandler'

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, solr5

On Solr 4.2.1, I was able to use the solr post and now I have upgraded to 5.4 and when I used the post method. I am getting **Error loading class 'solr.XsltUpdateRequestHandler'** error.

Here is the complete error:

```
null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.XsltUpdateRequestHandler'
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:559)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:490)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.XsltUpdateRequestHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
```

I have used the following on the solrconfig and no errors during the solr start.

```
<requestHandler name="/update/xslt" class="solr.XsltUpdateRequestHandler" startup="lazy" />
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that handler was deprecated back in 4.8 or possibly even sooner than that. I wouldn't be surprised if it was removed from Solr completely by 5.0, but I don't see anything in the docs about it. [I pulled up the 4.2.1 docs and even those have the deprecated annotation](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-core/index.html?org/apache/solr/handler/XsltUpdateRequestHandler.html).

You might want to try to downgrade all the way back to 4.10 at the latest to see if you can use that handler, then start upgrading versions one at a time until the error happens again. Jumping from 4.2.1 to 5.4.1 is huge. There have been quite a few changes between these versions.

If you don't want to bother, I did a quick search in my 5.4.1 `solrconfig.xml` and found the following:

```
<!-- XSLT response writer transforms the XML output by any xslt file found
       in Solr's conf/xslt directory.  Changes to xslt files are checked for
       every xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds.  
    -->
  <queryResponseWriter name="xslt" class="solr.XSLTResponseWriter">
    <int name="xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds">5</int>
  </queryResponseWriter>
```

I don't know how to use this as I've never had a reason to bother with xslt, but it looks like a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TMBT for your response. I was able to find the solution by using it UpdateRequestHandler as XsltUpdateRequestHandler is deprecated. After changing it to solr.UpdateRequestHandler, I was able to run the solr POST and it was successful.

```
<requestHandler name="/update/xslt" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" startup="lazy" />
```